# Whats the difference between .map.js file and .min.js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know both are minified version of js. 
but how they are different and which is the Best among them?

Comment: `map.js` is nothing of the sort. `min.js` is minified code, and is still executable. `map.js` shows correlation between source code and transpiled code, so that the browser will allow you to debug using the source code, and is _not_ executable.

Comment: `.min.js` is s minified version of the js code. And the corresponding `.map.js` file allows to map to the original not minified version.

Answer (score 0):

The map file maps the unminified file to the minified file. If you make changes in the unminified file, the changes will be automatically reflected to the minified version of the file.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you make changes in the unminified file, the only way they propagate to the minified file is by running the minifier - it has nothing to do with the map file (except for the fact that the minifier will generate a new map in the process). The map file is used on the clientside for debugging purposes, not to propagate changes.